# PHPStorm - убрать автокомплит

Tags: phpstorm

Добрый день.

При вводе текста в окне редактора кода автоматически выскакиваем подсказки (автокомплит), так-же его можно вызвать через Ctr+пробел.

Хочется сделать так, чтобы автоматически ничего не всплывало, только через Ctr+пробел (когда мне это нужно).

Подскажите, как отключить автоматическое всплытие подсказок, но при этом сохранить их при Ctr+пробел.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File->Settings...->Editor->General->Code Completion-> Autopop code completion снять галочку.

Comment: Да не за что :)